# Removed features on openlayers 3 is re-rendered on zoom in/out

Tags: openlayers, openlayers-2

In map I have Vector with Features inside, upon selecting some other options those features should be changed, therefore, I grab the map, select vector that I need, grab source from that map, and then I can remove feature. There are multiple ways that can be done:

```
this.map.getLayers().a[i].getSource().removeFeature(this.map.getLayers().a[i].getSource().B[2]);
```

or

```
this.map.getLayers().a[i].getSource().clear()
```

Where i is iteration through all layers.

In both cases, selected feature/features are removed from map. BUT if I try to zoom in/zoom out, that features that I have removed are re-rendered again. Is that some sort of cache? How can I remove them permanently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution is that I have to clear vector source and also cluster source.

https://github.com/openlayers/ol3/issues/5437

Answer (score 0):

could you please provide a jsfiddle with your example ?
Maybe try with map.render() after your clear() method but in my case, there is no issue with deleting features.

Comment: Hmm, regarding jsfiddle, I will see if I can make it tomorrow from work.. At least smaller version because current one is around 500 lines and infused with react js. Will try the map.render()